# Control not reaching to Specific Location in Scala Nested Map

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

```
def startProcessing() = {
   readQuery
  .eventsByTag(TaggingEventAdapter.driverStateEvent, Offset.noOffset)
  .groupedWithin(5, 2.seconds)
  .mapAsync(1) { envelopes =>
    processEvents(envelopes.map(_.event)).map(_ => envelopes.last.offset).map{
      offset => self ! UpdateOffsetCommand(TaggingEventAdapter.driverStateEvent, offset)
    }
  }
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
}

def processEvents(events: Seq[Any]): Future[Unit] = {
log.info(events.toString())
null
}
```

When my code control is not reaching to 
`map{offset => self ! UpdateOffsetCommand(TaggingEventAdapter.TestStateEvent, offset)}` Location,

Given that eventsByTag is getting two events in vector. `envelopes` Also Events. But it's not reaching to Third `map`

Answer (score 1):

Your `processEvents` method looks highly suspicious in that it returns a `null`. Change it to the following (assuming that the return type of `log.info` is `Unit`):

```
def processEvents(events: Seq[Any]): Future[Unit] = Future {
  log.info(events.toString())
}
```

Comment: But It won't create an issue. If you See `map(_ => envelopes.last.offset)` is using `envelopes` whatever previous instruction(`processEvents(envelopes.map(_.event))`) returning.

Comment: @Merom, what in your opinion is the object that `.map(_ => envelopes.last.offset)` is called upon?

Comment: Whatever returned by `processEvents(envelopes.map(_.event))` won't affect `.map(_ => envelopes.last.offset)`. I guess. What about you @SergGr

Comment: @Merom, try to split the code assigning result of `processEvents` to a `val` and then applying the next `map` and try to debug it. I think you'll get a surprise.

Comment: @Merom, here is a hint for you: `NullPointerException` is a real thing in the Scala world and `mapAsync` wrapper call probably makes it less obvious.

Comment: I am very new to Scala/Akka thing. Can you help me on this, please?